# Twitter Oauth problem - I need a website to register an app

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, registration

I need to use Oauth for a personal twitter script I am making. Its not commercial or anything like that. To register it here: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new I need a website even though it is a client. It wont let me register my app without a website.

Is there anything I can do? If I just created a blog that explains the concept behind the script I am using - would they accept that and let me register the "app" (just a script I use?).

Answer (score 1):

Choose `Client` [here](https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new):
[image: Application Type]

In place of **Application Website** you can put any link. Its just the link-back url.

Comment: I still need to give a website for a client unfortunately.

Comment: In place of **Application Website** you can put any link. Don't you have any online presence.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just for personal use, you could put pretty much any url in that field. As far as I know it isn't double checked or subjected to approval.

Comment: It's not.  I've put gibberish in that field before

Comment: Yep, just link it to your SO user page: http://stackoverflow.com/users/819759/phil

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the callback URL can be anything, but I would choose **Browser**, not Client, because Twitter lets you override the value of Application Website with the parameter `oauth_callback`. This lets you automate the final step of the OAuth flow.

Usually, since you are running a script, you would need to set `oauth_callback=oob` and put the user through PIN authentication, which sucks. Here is an alternative:

- Choose Browser and set *Application Website* to http://www.whatever.com (doesn't matter).
- Register your script with your operative system to handle a custom scheme, eg: `myscript://`
- Pass `oauth_callback=myscript://anystring` during the OAuth flow.

The result is that once the user is authenticated, Twitter calls `myscript://anything` from the web browser with the two last parameters you need for the final authentication step, and the OAuth flow will complete without user interaction.

Comment: Hi Jano: I performed your steps. Twitter didn't accept something like myscript:// it replied with 'Not a valid URL format'

Comment: Use any http address when you register your application with Twitter. Use a custom URI (myscript://something) during the OAuth flow, not in the Twitter site.